# how to change gtk default font in xfce4?

Tags: xfce, fonts, gtk

I'm not sure if this is Debian 12 issue or an xfce4 (4.18) issue or a GTK (3.24) issue: various applications let you choose fonts for this or that, but, particularly in pop up dialogue boxes, there seems to be a default font that the applications don't control.  I'm told this is a GTK thing.  Anyway, the default font is pretty ugly, it looks like an old typewriter font like Courier.  Can I change it?  And if so, where can I see a list of the available options?